# SkiaSharp basic animation speed different on different screen sizes

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, skiasharp, skia

I'm trying to make a very basic animation with SkiaSharp in Xamarin. Basically a small point spinning in a circle. 
A basic `Timer` does the job, however **i can't keep a consistent speed for the animation** across different devices. The speed of the animation changes drastically based on the screen size (for example if i switch to Landscape the animation is about half as slow).

This is my code:

```
protected override void OnPaintSurface(SKPaintSurfaceEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnPaintSurface(e);

    SKSurface surface = e.Surface;
    SKCanvas canvas = surface.Canvas;

    canvas.Clear();

    int width = e.Info.Width;
    int height = e.Info.Height;

    canvas.Translate(width / 2, height / 2);
    canvas.Scale(0.2f, 0.2f);
    canvas.Save();
    float radiusDot = radius * 8;
    canvas.DrawCircle((float)(radiusDot * Math.Sin(degree * (Math.PI / 180))), (float)(radiusDot * Math.Cos(degree * (Math.PI / 180))), 100, blueFillPoint);
    canvas.Restore();
    canvas.Save();
}
```

and the timers:

```
Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5), () =>
{
    if (degree == 0) degree = 360;
    else degree -= 2;
    if (degreeTail == 360) degreeTail = 0;
    else degreeTail += 2;
    return true;
});

Device.StartTimer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1f / 120), () =>
{
    this.InvalidateSurface();
    return true;
});
```

Comment: first, try using System.Timers.Timer instead

Comment: I usually always prefere `System.Timers.Timer` over the Device Timer but in this case for some reason i don't understand, with the System Timer the SkiaSharp canvas doesn't refresh automatically (only when i change orientation)

Comment: Device.StartTimer is probably running on the UI thread

Comment: You are right Jason. Inside the function that i'm calling with my `System.Timers.Timer` i invoked the code in the MainThread and now i got a synchronous animation on every screen resolution. Feel free to post an answer so i can mark it as accepted.

Comment: 5ms is a little bit too low - will teoretically yield in 200 fps.